# Different ways to pass a Object in C#

Tags: c#, class, new-operator

I'm in need of clarification with regards the way in which a object can be return from a  method in C#.  I have the following class;

```
public class Person
{
    public string Forename {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

My generic function is;

```
public static Person MyFunction()
{
    Person oPerson = new Person();
    oPerson.Forename = "Joe";
    oPerson.Surname = "King";
    return oPerson;
}
```

Is there any different between the following two calls

```
Person oPerson = new Person();
oPerson = MyFunction();
```

and

```
Person oPerson = MyFunction();
```

Is it correct to call the new operator like

```
Person oPerson = new Person();
```

even though the generic function is creating a new instance of this object and returning it.

Comment: Is your question well redacted? Do you really mean to compare `Person oPerson = new Person();
oPerson = MyFunction();` to `Person oPerson = MyFunction();`

Comment: The `new Person()` call in your example is just bloat, it allocates and object and then throws it away. Question is though, why you would have `MyFunction` instead of making a proper Person constructor.

Comment: I don't want to do any compare.  I want to create the object.  My question is as above, what is the preferred way of creating a object and have a method return a new instance to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, no your calls are not the same.

```
Person oPerson = new Person(); // This object is about to be discarded by...
oPerson = MyFunction(); // ... Overwriting the reference to it here
```

At this point the first `Person` you created can be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

If you have default initialization you ought to do that in a constructor for `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the result object in oPerson should be exactly the same. The only difference I can see is, that

```
Person oPerson = new Person();
oPerson = MyFunction();
```

needs more time to execute because you are creating the object twice.

However, I don't see how your function

```
public static Person MyFunction()
{
    Person oPerson = new Person();
    oPerson.Forename = "Joe";
    oPerson.Surname = "King";
    return oPerson;
}
```

is generic as it only handles one type. Generic function look like this:

```
public static <T> SomeGenericFunction(T person) where T : Person
{
    person.Forename = "Joe";
    person.Surname = "King";
    return person;

}
```

Comment: This was purely for example purposes, obviously a generic function would use <T>